schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010 returns 404
All scripts Natvis for debuggers use the address http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010, but by going to this address we get error 4xx error. does anyone know what's going on here or am I misunderstanding how this piece works xml:
<AutoVisualizer xmlns=“http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010“>

and where should I look for file which this link used to lead to?. (*\Xml\Schemas\1033\natvis.xsd and in other folders - not exist).
I looked at the address history in the web archiveI looked at the address history in the web archive.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/natvis#_schema contains the schema in full

From XML namespace: "the namespace specification does not require nor suggest that the namespace URI be used to retrieve information; it is simply treated by an XML parser as a string."
